How do I get the string dd.mm.yyyy and how can I convert it depending on the user's locale?
How can I get the string dd.mm.yyyy in JavaScript and convert it depending on the user's locale (for example, дд.мм.гггг)? Is it possible with the help of internal functions, or will you have to write your own converter?
I tried to find a solution in Datе and Intl.DateTimeFormat, but I didn't find it there.

so, you don't want to convert dates, just strings?

yes, I only want to convert strings

why can't you cast the string as date (new Date(string)) and then use toLocalized date helpers ?

@lovis91 I don't need to get the date, I need to get the string depending on the locale. I need this to design an empty string for the date

The answer is no. There is no way you can get дд.мм.гггг from _RU or dd/mm/åååå for Norway/Denmark using JS

You are confusing locale with language. A locale is a place, and is used with date formatting to mean "the format used in this place". Unfortunately, the related specification, ECMA-402 uses a BCP47 language tag to specify place, so calls the parameter "locale" rather than "language". What you are attempting to do is change the language of dd.mm.yyyy (English) to some other language, such as дд.мм.гггг (Russian). You should rethink your strategy—placeholders and help text should be in the language of the page, not some other language like browser default, which might be anything.

The answer is no. There is no way you can get дд.мм.гггг from _RU or dd/mm/åååå for Norway/Denmark using plain JS/INTL
Here is the closest you can get using a lookup table with a locale as input


const localizedPlaceholders = {
    'ru-RU': 'дд.мм.гггг',  // Russian
    'no-NO': 'dd/mm/åååå',  // Norwegian
    'da-DK': 'dd/mm/åååå',  // Danish
    'en-US': 'MM/dd/yyyy',  // US English
    'en-GB': 'dd/MM/yyyy',  // British English
    // Add other locales as needed
};
const deflt = 'en-GB'
const getDatePlaceholder = (locale) => localizedPlaceholders[locale] || localizedPlaceholders[deflt]


console.log(getDatePlaceholder('ru-RU')); // Output: "дд.мм.гггг"
console.log(getDatePlaceholder('no-NO')); // Output: "dd/mm/åååå"
console.log(getDatePlaceholder('da-DK')); // Output: "dd/mm/åååå"
console.log(getDatePlaceholder('en-US')); // Output: "MM/dd/yyyy"
console.log(getDatePlaceholder('xx-YY')); // Output: "dd/MM/yyyy"



Here is IMNHO OK hack for moment - there is code present so you can handle formats not covered by moment or where the dd.mm.yyyy is incorrect for that language


const getDDMMYYY = locale => {
  const m = moment('2016-01-01 00:00:00').locale(locale);
  const relativeTime = m.creationData().locale._relativeTime;
  let {
    d: day,
    M: month,
    y: year
  } = relativeTime;

  // console.log(locale,day,month,year)

  // If we get a function instead of a string, call it
  if (typeof day === 'function') {
    day = day(1, false, 'd', false); // Call with parameters to get the singular form
    month = month(1, false, 'M', false); // Call with parameters to get the singular form
    year = year(1, false, 'y', false); // Call with parameters to get the singular form
  }
  // if (["id"].includes(locale)) { console.log(relativeTime); } // debug country
  if (["ar", ",jp", "sw"].includes(locale)) {
    switch (locale) {
      case "ar": 
        { // Arabic locale handling
          return `يي.شش.عععع`
          // Set placeholders directly for Arabic
          day = "يي"; // Placeholder for day in Arabic
          month = "شش"; // Placeholder for month in Arabic
          year = "عععع"; // Placeholder for year in Arabic
          break;
        }
      case "ja":
        { // Japanese locale handling
          return  `日日.月月.年年年年`
          day = "日日"; // Placeholder for day in Japanese
          month = "月月"; // Placeholder for month in Japanese
          year = "年年年年"; // Placeholder for year in Japanese
          break;
        }
      case "sw":
        { // swahili
          // sw: siku moja mwezi mmoja mwaka mmoja
          day = day.split(' ')[0];
          month = month.split(' ')[0];
          year = year.split(' ')[0];
          break;
        }
    }
  }
  // "a day" "en dag" etc
  if (day.split(' ').length > 1) day = day.split(' ')[1];
  if (month.split(' ').length > 1) month = month.split(' ')[1];
  if (year.split(' ').length > 1) year = year.split(' ')[1];
  // "d": "1something"
  if (day.startsWith('1')) day = day.slice(1)
  if (month.startsWith('1')) month = month.slice(1)
  if (year.startsWith('1')) year = year.slice(1)


  // Extract and double the first letter
  const dd = day.slice(0, 1).repeat(2); // дд or tt
  const mm = month.slice(0, 1).repeat(2); // мм
  const yyyy = year.slice(0, 1).repeat(4); // гггг or jjjj

  if (dd === mm === yyyy) console.log(`Something failed for ${locale}`, day, month, year, relativeTime)

  return `${dd}.${mm}.${yyyy}`;
};

document.getElementById('output').textContent = isoTwoLetterLanguageCodes.map(lg => `${lg}:${getDDMMYYY(lg)}`).join('\n');
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.30.1/moment-with-locales.min.js" integrity="sha512-4F1cxYdMiAW98oomSLaygEwmCnIP38pb4Kx70yQYqRwLVCs3DbRumfBq82T08g/4LJ/smbFGFpmeFlQgoDccgg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<pre id="output"></pre>

<script>
  const isoTwoLetterLanguageCodes = [
    "af", // Afrikaans
    "am", // Amharic
    "ar", // Arabic
    "as", // Assamese
    "az", // Azerbaijani
    "be", // Belarusian
    "bg", // Bulgarian
    "bn", // Bengali
    "bs", // Bosnian
    "ca", // Catalan
    "cs", // Czech
    "cy", // Welsh
    "da", // Danish
    "de", // German
    "el", // Greek
    "en", // English
    "eo", // Esperanto
    "es", // Spanish
    "et", // Estonian
    "eu", // Basque
    "fa", // Persian
    "fi", // Finnish
    "fr", // French
    "ga", // Irish
    "gl", // Galician
    "gu", // Gujarati
    "he", // Hebrew
    "hi", // Hindi
    "hr", // Croatian
    "hu", // Hungarian
    "hy", // Armenian
    "id", // Indonesian
    "is", // Icelandic
    "it", // Italian
    "ja", // Japanese
    "jv", // Javanese
    "ka", // Georgian
    "kk", // Kazakh
    "km", // Khmer
    "kn", // Kannada
    "ko", // Korean
    "lo", // Lao
    "lt", // Lithuanian
    "lv", // Latvian
    "mk", // Macedonian
    "ml", // Malayalam
    "mn", // Mongolian
    "mr", // Marathi
    "ms", // Malay
    "mt", // Maltese
    "my", // Burmese
    "ne", // Nepali
    "nl", // Dutch
    "no", // Norwegian
    "or", // Odia
    "pa", // Punjabi
    "pl", // Polish
    "pt", // Portuguese
    "ro", // Romanian
    "ru", // Russian
    "si", // Sinhala
    "sk", // Slovak
    "sl", // Slovenian
    "sq", // Albanian
    "sr", // Serbian
    "sv", // Swedish
    "sw", // Swahili
    "ta", // Tamil
    "te", // Telugu
    "th", // Thai
    "tl", // Tagalog
    "tr", // Turkish
    "uk", // Ukrainian
    "ur", // Urdu
    "uz", // Uzbek
    "vi", // Vietnamese
    "zh", // Chinese
    "zu" // Zulu
  ];
</script>




"ru-RU" is a BCP47 language tag. The ECMA-402 authors seem to have created much confusion regarding language/locale.

Great effort, but It's a little more complex than that. Arabic is right–to–left, the word "day" is "يوم" (yawm) and the first letter in its isolated form is "ي". Arabic letters have up to 4 different forms depending on whether they're at the start, middle or end of a word, or isolated. Your code prints "وو.وو.وووو" for language ar, which translates to English  "woo.woo.woo". The letter "و" is a conjunction, equivalent to English "and". The Japanese "日日.ヶヶ.年年年年" according to Google translate is "Day by day. Day by day. Year by year". :-)

I know. Hence if (["sw"].includes(locale)) { ... 

I don't think you will be able to do this without a hard coded function. But maybe something like that can fit your needs:
const date = new Date();
const options = { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' };
const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString(undefined, options);

Here the documentation for more options.
If you need to get the format from a string, you'll need to use a library like moment:
moment('2016-01-01 00:00:00').creationData().format

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/creation-data/

Here I get the current date(14.08.2024), but I need to get dd.mm.yyyy

OP wants to get дд.мм.гггг from ru_RU and dd/mm/åååå from no_NO or da_DK - likely as a placeholder in a date field

Since momentjs can do this, you can do this in plain JS

@lovis91 What is the momentjs code to do this? Also moment is deprecated for Luxon

i already added an example to my answer

No you did not. Show me how you will get дд.мм.гггг from ru_RU and dd/mm/åååå  from da_DK

yes i did. '2016-01-01 00:00:00' is the string you can get from a localized date (new Date with browser in fr_FR in my case). moment('2016-01-01 00:00:00').creationData().format will print YYYY-mm-dd. If you try this in a da_DK localized browser you'll get the corresponding format string.

That is not what OP wants. See my answer. You get YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss for moment('2016-01-01 00:00:00').locale('ru').creationData().format and not дд.мм.гггг

The OP doesn't want localised formatting, they want fixed formatting (dd.mm.yyyy) but to have the help text in different languages. The Russian example literally translates back to English as dd.mm.gggg because the Russian words for day and month start with Russian equivalents of d and m respectively. But the Russian word for year is год, where the first letter г translates to English "g". PS I used a translator service to do Russian/English translations so there might be errors but it seems to be what the OP is after.
